# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, unable to access admin console

Tags: parsing, syntax, admin

I have what I perceive to be an unusual "syntax" error (at least to my very rookie junior dev self it is unusual)

I have a WP website that was originally built and designed by a friend,  who wanted me to help. After logging on and attempting to upload a new theme to the website, legendsofthestands.com, I received the following error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
/home/kcsuperf/public_html/legendsofthestands.com/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/functions.php 
on line 1028
```

The problem isn't so much the error message, it is now that I'm not able to access the admin login page without seeing the same error. My understanding is that this is due to plugins that need to be deactivated so that I can access the /wp-admin page. However, when I try to access the admin console via FTP, I keep getting the 530 login failed error message.

I'm not sure which route to go at this point, whether I should try and contact the hosting company to resolve the logon issue, or if there is a way to fix the parse/syntax issue without having seen the code (since it is a WP-installed site).

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You mention FTP. Can you FTP `functions.php` from your hosting provider to your local environment so you can inspect it?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm a VERY junior dev.

Comment: I'm sure a quick google on how to use a FTP client will get you there.

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-use-ftp-to-upload-files-to-wordpress-for-beginners/

"There are times when you install and activate a plugin using the WordPress dashboard just to find that this plugin is incompatible with an existing plugin. The incompatibility sometimes causes a white screen of death through out the site which locks you out from doing anything. If you know how to use FTP, then instead of freaking out, you will simply login-in and delete the plugin using the FTP connection"

Closest answer I have found so far... waiting to see who the hosting co is.